# OpenGL and Windows Programming C++

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

If I want to begin learning OpenGL and am not concerned about portability at the moment, would it be unwise to use OpenGL and Windows Programming together? (I am developing on Windows)

Comment: openGL is cross platform (and language) API for graphics programming. It doesn't really matter what OS you develop with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all.  If you already know the Windows API/message pump, adding the OpenGL context management bits won't be too much of a problem.

If you're new to both Windows programming AND OpenGL, I'd recommend starting with GLUT or similar frameworks that will let you focus on the OpenGL bits without worrying too much about interacting with the window system.

Comment: I'm not entirely new to Windows programming, but there's so much caution tape on the internet about GLUT being outdated. I figured it would be easier if I just used the Windows API

Comment: @Biostreem: GLUT is outdated. FreeGLUT is not.

Comment: @Biostream:  I guess the "modern" version of GLUT is freeglut (http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), still being maintained as of January 2012.  Take it for what it is--not a full blown GUI toolkit for developing real apps, but instead a canvas that lets you twiddle with OpenGL fairly painlessly.  When you're ready to incorporate GL into a real app, you can go direct to the Windows API or any number of GUI libraries (Qt, wxWidgets, FLTK, etc.) that provide GL support.